# sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID > essid.txt (How do I export without the word ESSID in txt file)

Tags: grep, output

So my goal is to answer my other question I am working on. Which is [Connect to Open Wifi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250562/auto-connect-to-any-open-wifi-network). Currently I am getting close, as I know there is only one Wifi connection, I would like to export the results of

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID
```

to a text file. The output currently is:

```
ESSID: "MyNetworkSSID"  # Which would end up being in the file
```

What I want is a text file that says only

"MyNetworkSSID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with `grep`.  Pipe it directly to `awk` as follows:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | awk -F ':' '/ESSID:/ {print $2;}'
"BTWifi-with-FON"
"BTHub5-FTQN"
"BTWifi-X"
"4GEEOnetouchY800z_2DEB"
```

This carries out a regexp search for `ESSID:` and the splits that line on a colon (`-F ':'`) after which it prints the second element of that split (`print $2`).

Or, pipe it through `perl`:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | perl -nle '/ESSID:(.*)$/ && print $1'
```

This causes `perl` to run the command (`-e`) on each line of the input (`-n`) and adds a line feed at the end of each line (`-l`).  The command is a regex which searches for `ESSID:` and captures the remaining line (`(.*)$`).  On finding this match, it prints the capture (`&& print $1`).

Comment: can you elaborate on why not to use grep? awk seems to be the agreed method, but grep worked fine as well for me

Comment: Simply because it's one less command? If you use `grep` you end up piping it's output through something else anyway (or `grep` again).  Why not ditch `grep` altogether and pipe it directly to something that is more capable? I didn't mean to sound anti-grep :-)

Answer (score 0):

***Try***

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -i essid | awk -F'"' '{ print $2 }' >> essid.txt`

This pipes the output of `grep` to `awk`, which uses the delimiter of `"` and only prints the field with ESSID.

Comment: that just showed a number, but I only copy and pasted, didn't troubleshoot as I figured it out! Thank you tho

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I didn't actually test this, I was assuming the fields were tab separated like OP shows. Answer is now adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Hazar, this worked, but it is more case specific as it has to do with the double quotes vs excluding the word ESSID.

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID | grep -o '"[^"]\+"' >> essid.txt
```